# Why two inverters cascaded in multiplexer control signal terminals?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, multiplexer, inverter

Why cascaded inverters are used in the multiplexer when it is possible to realize the circuit using a single inverter.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The front inverters are used to buffer the input signal. Without the front inverters inputs A and B would be 3 load units each instead of 1, since you would have to drive both the rear inverters as well as both of the and gates used with the input's term in the multiplexer logic.

Comment: front inverters means inverters on the right side ?

Comment: On the left side. The ones on the right side are used for logic purposes.

Comment: "Without the front inverters inputs A and B would be 3 load units each instead of 1."  Can you please elaborate this point ?

Comment: @tollin: Updated.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams please make it more clear..?

Comment: @BASILVARGHESE: Which part is unclear?

Comment: "Without the front inverters inputs A and B would be 3 load units each instead of 1" In this you meant 3 loads as AND Gates??? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: @BASILVARGHESE: As the answer explains, one of the loads is the other inverter and the other two are and gates. The 2-input multiplexer equation uses each of the non-inverted inputs twice.